# Is it possible to decode/encode this without losing some value using 360 int to 1 byte

Tags: java

Is it possible to decode/encode this without losing some value using 360 int to 1 byte

Im currently finding a way to reduce 360 to fit in 255 max value of a byte.

this is what i tried:

```
  public static int getBearing(byte data){
        return Integer.parseInt( Integer.toHexString(data & 0xff) , 16) << 1;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
      for(int bearing = 0 ; bearing < 360 ; bearing++){
            final byte bearingByte = (byte) (bearing >> 1);
            System.out.printf("Bit {%s} , Original Bearing {%d} , Decrypted Bearing {%d} \n" , get8Bit(bearingByte) , bearing , getBearing(bearingByte));
      }
  }
```

and output is :

```
Bit {00000000} , Original Bearing {0} , Decrypted Bearing {0} 
Bit {00000000} , Original Bearing {1} , Decrypted Bearing {0} <-- this should be 1
Bit {00000001} , Original Bearing {2} , Decrypted Bearing {2} 
Bit {00000001} , Original Bearing {3} , Decrypted Bearing {2} <-- this should be 3
Bit {00000010} , Original Bearing {4} , Decrypted Bearing {4} 
Bit {00000010} , Original Bearing {5} , Decrypted Bearing {4} <-- this should be 5
Bit {00000011} , Original Bearing {6} , Decrypted Bearing {6} 
Bit {00000011} , Original Bearing {7} , Decrypted Bearing {6} <-- this should be 7
Bit {00000100} , Original Bearing {8} , Decrypted Bearing {8} 
Bit {00000100} , Original Bearing {9} , Decrypted Bearing {8} <-- this should be 8
```

Seems like everything in decrypted is even integers.

> Is there a formula or trick so that i could not lose some value?

Comment: Are you asking for a yes/no answer? Because it looks like your asking for number 4 of our [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) list

Comment: yes with a solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to decode/encode this without losing some value using 360 int to 1 byte.

No.  It is impossible.

Any encoding from a larger domain (360 values) to a smaller one (256 values) must be be lossy<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - One way to prove it is by application of the "[pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)".</sup>